# How to add timestamp to my document in cloud Firestore using Firebase Python Admin SDK?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to add a timestamp value, along with other details to a comment document in Cloud Firestore. I would like to know how can I do it using Firebase Admin Python SDK.
As far as I know to get server time stamp, in JS SDK you use

```
admin.firestore().Field value.serverTimestamp()
```

Is there any Python SDK equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html):

> To set a field to the current time on the server when the update is
>   received, use the SERVER_TIMESTAMP sentinel.

```
>>> field_updates = {
...     'foo.now': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
... }
>>> document.update(field_updates)
```